# change doubleclick behavior

Tags: gnome, mouse, compiz, gui, doubleclick

Is it possible to change doubleclick detection from double mouseDOWN to double mouseUP ?

as it is on down, quite often the 2nd mousedown puts me into another context, now with mousedown, possibly scrolling, so that I sometimes find myself with a hundred lines of text all of a sudden selected in another application, and other fun scenarios.

I see that you can read mouse ups and downs from /dev/input/mice and /dev/input/event, but where are these being interpreted into OS events ?

Comment: Whether or not this is possible, I'm not sure it is advisable. Think about where you want to double click and drag to make a text selection. If the double click isn't activated until the mouse up, you will then have to click again(?) to make the text selection? Is many cases the triple-click action would do yet some other action. Just sayin.

Comment: good thought, but I checked into how OSX does it (my main inspiration here) and it fires different events for '2nd mousedown` (begins dragging) and '2nd mouseup' (executes doubleclick)
So this is kind of a complicated topic actually.  Not only do you have to make that kind of differentiation, but I imagine there is also some disagreement between the OS and the applications that needs priority settings.
Hopefully most apps take their cue from the OS settings.  Still don't know where the mouse events are intepreted by the OS though.